# HOW TO BRING CENTRE ALIGNMENT IN WEB PAGE USING HTML?

Tags: html, html5, code, public-html, webpage

In html, what can we write in the code to bring the content of my web page in the center ??
I have tried to write the code within "center" tag and "/center" but it's not working. so any other alternatives ??

Comment: Questions about [coding/programming](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site and best asked over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You simply limit the width of a block element and define automatic margins or if you want to center the text just use text-align. You can use a CSS class or style the element directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .center {
        margin: auto;
        width: 60%;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```